# Is it safe to get all tag params in one go with $this->EE->TMPL->tagparams?

Tags: add-on-development, plugin, parameters

*Apologies if this is very obvious for experienced addon devs, but I'm experimenting with writing more bespoke plugins rather than gluing together other people's...*

I know the official way to fetch parameters is one-by-one by name with `$this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('key')`, but I'm currently writing a plugin in which I'd like to iterate over my tag's parameters without having to define in advance what those parameters are in my plugin class.

I see that I can access the tag parameters array directly via `$this->EE->TMPL->tagparams`, **but is it safe to do so?**

As far as I can see from reading the Template parser source, `fetch_param()` just does a bit of tidying up to ensure tag params are uniformly formatted and returns false if a requested param is not set, neither of which are a concern in my use case. However, I want to be sure I'm not introducing unnecessary fragility (or indeed a vulnerability) into my plugin inadvertently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the `fetch_param()` method in the Template library. There you can see all it does is return the value of the given key in the `tagparams` array, offering a fallback default.

So, it should be completely safe, unless EllisLab decides to make it a private property, which I doubt they'll do.

Comment: Thanks Low, thought that was the case but wanted to be sure I wasn't doing something stupid!

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of add-ons rely on that public `tagparams` property (ours included). So you would certainly not be the first to rely on it (e.g. my answer [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/5796/150)).

That doesn't mean EllisLab won't change/break it in future, but rest assured your add-on won't be the only one that breaks :)