# channel entries tag seems to run before my module function

Tags: channel-entries, add-on-development, php, module

The {exp:bmi_favorite:list_ids entry_type="recipe" site_id="1"} outputs 18|19 to be passed to the entry_id parameter. It does not work, unless I manually add the 18|19 into the entry_id, like entry_id="18|19". That leads me to believe my module function (list_ids) is running after the exp:channel:entries tag. Is it possible to run list_ids first, without having to tweak the settings for the template the code is in?

I also tried changing the single quotes to double quotes and that did not change anything.

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="recipes"
    entry_id='{exp:bmi_favorite:list_ids entry_type="recipe" site_id="1"}'
}

    <h2>{title}</h2>

{/exp:channel:entries}


public function list_ids()
{
    $entry_type = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('entry_type', false);

    if($entry_type == false)
        return 'Please provide valid entry_type';

    $site_id = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('site_id', '1');

    $where_data = array(
        'site_id'       =>  $site_id,
        'user_id'       =>  $this->EE->session->userdata('member_id'),
        'entry_type'    =>  $entry_type,  
    );

    $query = $this->EE->db->where($where_data)->get('bmi_favorite');

    if($query->num_rows == 0)
        return false;

    $i = 1;
    $output = '';

    foreach($query->result() as $row):
        $output .= $row->entry_id;
        $i++;

        if($i <= $query->num_rows)
            $output .= '|';
    endforeach;

    return $output;
}
```

UPDATE: I added parse='inward' to the end of my list_ids template tag, that did the trick, but I'd like it to do that without the user having to put parse='inward' themselves, is that possible or the user will always have to append parse="inward" onto my module tag?

Comment: To answer your follow-up question, if you're building a module for use by others, you can extend the channel entries tag with your module. Take a look at the second part of the answer for this question: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5785/how-to-create-a-plugin-which-returns-channel-entry-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add `parse="inward"` to your channel entries tag parameters, it will force module tags inside your parameters to be parsed before the channel entries tag.