# One most recent entry from multiple channels

Tags: channel-entries, date, orderby, loop

I'd like to return 5 entries from 5 channels in a list, the list being comprised of:

- the one most recent entry from each channel
- in order of date

A simple exp:channel:entries loop with a limit of 5 and channel="blog1|blog2|blog3|blog4|blog5" will bring back the 5 most recent entries overall, but not just one entry per channel.

And 5 channel:entries loops will bring back the most recent, but not with them in the right order -- and the overhead of 5 channel:entries loops makes me cringe.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in custom plugin territory Travis. Pretty easy though.

- Run one (very quick) query to get the latest `entry_id` in each channel (query `exp_channel_titles` only). Save them all to an array.
- Then, you can either return those entry_ids as a variable (concatenated with `|`), which you pass to your `channel:entries` tag in your template, or instantiate a new Channel instance and return it directly.

See [this great answer on a related question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/5796/55) by Adrian for some sample code.