# Call for support for Feature request: Search Module parameter: future_entry_channels

Tags: feature-request

I've got a reply from EllisLab on a feature request, they only want to implement the feature request, when enough of you request the feature, here it is:

**The search module is an all the way show_future_entries = yes or no. However, i have only one event channel for which i like to enable future_entries, 
the following couple of lines enables a "future_entry_channels" parameter that enables to set channels that allow future entries, instead of a general show_future_entries=yes**

*This would enable a future_entry_channels="7|3" parameter for channels that you want to allow search into future entries, please add a comment with +1.*

```
// ~ line 336 add a parameter
'future_entry_channels' => $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('future_entry_channels',''),

// ~ line 664 replace/extend show_future_entries conditional
if ( ! isset($this->_meta['show_future_entries']) OR $this->_meta['show_future_entries'] != 'yes')
{
    // Future entries for some channels, like event-channels
    $future_entry_channels = $this->_meta['future_entry_channels'];

    if(empty($future_entry_channels))
    {
         // regular show_future_entries="no"
         $sql .= "\nAND exp_channel_titles.entry_date < ".ee()->localize->now." ";
    }
    else
    {
        // allow some channels to have future entries
        $future_entry_channels = explode('|', $future_entry_channels);

        $sql .= "\nAND (exp_channel_titles.entry_date < ".ee()->localize->now." OR exp_channel_titles.channel_id IN(".implode(',', $future_entry_channels).") ) ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like the idea. EECMS have been depending on too much plugins for simple and useful features. I believe this should be part of core, but I don't know if this is the right place for ask for support.

Comment: I like the idea, but unfortunately feature requests are off topic for this site (and the whole stack exchange network), as the Q+A format really doesn't suit discussions.

Answer (score 1):

It does make sense, but seems just a bit too niche to be in core for me. How about you take your code and make it a wrapper for the core search and distribute it on Devot-ee?

Adrian Macneil has shared some code of how he wrapped the Channel Entries module in his own plugin and would be a good starting point: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/5796/96

TLDR: Yes to the feature. No for it being in core.

Comment: there's an idea \o/

Comment: well that was not easy, since the search module has no hooks and the build_query method is rather long to replicate.