# How to include search params in plugin with TMPL->tagparams

Tags: ee2, add-on-development, plugin

I'm building a custom plugin tag pair which returns channel entries, following the excellent answer to [this question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/5796/2838). Almost everything seems to be working: I set the `TMPL->tagparams` array to my custom params, instantiate a `new Channel()`, and return its entries.

I'm searching a "classes" channel where entries have a "weekday" custom field with values like "Monday", "Tuesday", etc. In the case, I want to return the first 5 classes on Mondays.

```
$this->EE->TMPL->tagparams = array('channel'        => 'classes',
                                   'limit'          => '5',
                                   'search:weekday' => '=Monday');

if ( ! class_exists('Channel')) {
  require_once(APPPATH.'modules/channel/mod.channel.php');
}
$channel = new Channel();

return $channel->entries();
```

EE seems to be ignoring the `search:weekday` param. It's returning the right channel and enforcing the limit, but it's returning all results, not just results with "Monday" for their "weekday" custom field. How can I use search params in a plugin like this?

**Update:** to provide more use-case info and clarify that I'm searching a custom field with the search param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search parameters belong in a different property of the Template object: `ee()->TMPL->search_fields`

So use something like this:

```
ee()->TMPL->search_fields['weekday'] = '=Monday';
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks, Low!

Answer (score 0):

Ah - this is because the `search` parameter will only search custom fields - it won't search the `title` (or any other field which resides in `exp_channel_titles` as opposed to `exp_channel_data`).

What you'll have to do if you want to support this in your plugin is check to see if that parameter was passed, and if so, do a separate database query for all titles including that phrase. Then, concatenate the resulting Entry IDs into a pipe-delimited string, and feed that back as the `entry_id` parameter on `ee()->TMPL->tagparams`.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping this would solve it, but it doesn't seem to work searching custom fields either. I've updated the question with this new, more correct use-case.